# When do stream object get deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, c++14

[Here's the text from the book that I referred to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiP0G.jpg)

According to what I read in a book(I have attached an image of the text from the book above), when a stream object goes out of scope, its connection with the program/file or whatever is closed but it still remains in the memory with the buffer that it is associated with.
So when does it deleted from the memory?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wording of your textbook is quite misleading.

When an object goes out of scope, it gets destroyed. When a *stream* is destroyed, its connection gets closed as if you would have manually called the `close()` function. Then, all the memory associated with the stream is released.

The author underlines that **the opposite does not hold**, i.e. if you call the `close()` method of a stream, you are not destroying it, you are just closing the connection with it.

Answer (score 1):

No, either your book is wrong, or you misunderstood it. When an `fstream` object is destroyed (i.e. is out of scope), its file descriptor will be closed and its `stream_buffer` will be deleted ass well.

Just guessing: Maybe the book is mixing pointers to `fstream` objects with `fstream` objects them self. When a pointer goes out of scope, the object it points to will not be destroyed.